# NSDateComponents keep changing the GMT?

Tags: objective-c

This might be basic but i couldn't find a similar problem to clearly understand that.

I have some date  which is this :

```
2015-07-19 12:00:00 +0000
```

then i am taking this date and try to get the hour of it with :

```
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour |NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear| NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:tdate];
    long hour=[components hour];
      NSLog(@"-- %ld ",hour);   //gives 15
```

Then i get the hour as **15** and not  **12** as the original date .
The 3 hours different is i guess my GMT +3 .
How can i get 12 - the original date hour ?

adding this

```
[components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

didn't helped.

When i create that original date with components class, i do it in the exact way that i later do it again, so there shouldn't be any change in the GMT times.

To create the original date i do :

```
 NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay |NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:new];

        [components setHour:12];
```

So, why when you extract it in the exact same way you dont get the same result ?

thanks .

Answer (score -1):

When Using `NSCalender` and `NSDateCompoment` it will always translate date to your systemDate. If you want to have that Date invariant and meanwhile use DateCompoment to access components you need to remove the timeInterval between your systemeData to that date system(GMT in your case).

```
NSTimeZone* currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSTimeInterval timeDiff = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:aGMTDate];
NSDate *gmtDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:(-timeDiff) sinceDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: I dont think its the case, because then he should show me the +0003 at the end of the date to let me know he added the 3 hours. what he does is to actually change the date, he shows a different hour, but not change the GMT sign to +0003 .

Comment: NSDate is immutable in itself but interpretation of its compoments using NSCalender + NSDateCompoment depends on your zone.

Comment: but i use the same calendar to create the date and to read the date, why then he show a different values ? its not that logic that with the exact same components you create a certain date, and then try to read it and get a different result. its like defining an integer then print it and get another result.

Comment: your date include reference to a specific time zone +000x,  else it will be systems timezone